# Turning archive templates to a page template maintaining the slug

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, urls, archives

I used to have an `archive-rooms.php` (as `page-rooms.php`) template to list them all

This had few problems:

- No title page
- No way to synch menu item with title

so:

1) I duplicated the archive-rooms and prepended to it:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Rooms Template
*/
?>
```

2) Created page, assigned the template and set the slug from the post type to the page
3) Removed `has_archive` from the `register_post_type()` arguments

Now the problem, when I open the page the content is not what I expected, expecially the class of the body:

```
<body class="blog">
```

Which **something** like this I was expecting:

```
<body class="page page-id-xx page-template-rooms etc..">
```

Any explanation/suggestion for this issue?

Thanks

Comment: In wp-admin, go to Settings > Reading. If "Posts page" is set to the page you have just created, that is why it is adding "blog" to the body class. If you don't have a generic post archive but do have a customized `front-page.php` it is safe to leave "Your homepage displays" set to "Your latest posts" and that also will keep WP from adding the "blog" class to the Page.

Comment: did you change the name of your copied php from archive-rooms.php to template-rooms.php?

Comment: @rudtek no, like I said. I duplicated the file with page-rooms.php ( archive-rooms.php still exist. I tried deleting but same result )

Comment: Try renaming it to template-rooms.php

Comment: How Do you think it would help ( which file, by the way ) ?

Comment: Have you flushed rewrite rules after changing the has_archive argument? You can do this by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page.

Comment: @Milo that solved my issue! please post an anser with the suggestion